# List of polysemy words

Tags: dataset, nlp, wordnet

I am trying to find list of polysemous words but did not get anything on internet. Can someone suggest me a source from where I can get it? I want to use it at backend of my word sense disambiguation project for polysemy detection mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

From  http://ixa2.si.ehu.es/signatureak/SENSECORPUS.README.TXT

> We say that a word is monosemous if it has a unique sense, that is, if
>   a word has a unique synset taking into account all its part of speech.

A polysemous word thus is one which has more than one sense. You can get this information from the wordnet itself.

Check out [this](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html).

The following will work:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def is_polysemous(word): 
    if(len(wn.synsets(word)) > 1): #more than 1 sense
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You can further qualify the code by adding POS. For example :

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def is_polysemous(word): 
    if(len(wn.synsets(word, pos=wn.NOUN)) > 1): #more than 1 sense
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: This is not useful as alomst all words in wordnet have more than one synset. Some of the synset are related and the word can not be considered as polysemy. e.g words like america, british are also considered as polysemy through this method

Comment: @Madhusudan Then you should be more clear about what you consider as polysemous. I have added references for my definition and another example.

Comment: @Madhusudan Perhaps you could use the distance in the wordnet tree between synsets as a way of distinguishing close polysemy from blatant polysemy? This answer looks correct for the question you have asked, however.

Answer (score 1):

WordNet has become more and more finely grained with each version. Take the example of the noun 'line'. In WordNet1.5, it had 6 senses, while WordNet3.0 lists 30 senses for the same noun.

@axiom has given you the correct answer, but if you do not want your application to be so specific you could chenge the WordNet version you are using or you could use the so-called 'sense mapping', which groups more related senses from a greater version (ex. 3.0) to the same sense in 1.5. 
You can find some sense mappings here http://www.cse.unt.edu/~rada/downloads.html#wordnet or, if you want different versions you can make your own mapping.